# initializing : cannot convert from LPVOID error

Tags: c++, cen-xfs

Ok I'm trying to write this under the WFSExecute but if I type:

```
WFSPINGETDATA * pingetdata = lpCmdData;
```

I get an error:

> errorC2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LPVOID' to 'WFSPINGETDATA *'

If I comment out that line, the app execute.

Also, if I write:

```
((WFSPINDATA*) (temp)) ->lpPinKeys = malloc(sizeof(LPWFSPINKEY)*NumberOfKeys) ;
```

I get an error:

> errorC2440: '='  cannot convert from 'void' to 'LPWFSPINKEY *'

Any solution to solve this?

Comment: In C++ you must explicitly cast from `void*` to other pointer type. In C, it's recommended to not use the cast. I'm curious why don't you use `operator new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is more strict on type safety than C is.  In this case, `void*` must be type-casted when assigned to anything other than another `void*`.

> ```
> WFSPINGETDATA * pingetdata = lpCmdData;
> ```
>
> cannot convert from 'LPVOID' to 'WFSPINGETDATA *'

This means `lpCmdData` is a `void*`, so a type-cast is needed:

```
WFSPINGETDATA * pingetdata = (WFSPINGETDATA*) lpCmdData;
```

Or, using a C++-style cast instead of a C-style cast:

```
WFSPINGETDATA * pingetdata = static_cast<WFSPINGETDATA*>(lpCmdData);
```

> ```
> ((WFSPINDATA*) (temp)) ->lpPinKeys = malloc(sizeof(LPWFSPINKEY)*NumberOfKeys) ;
> ```
>
> cannot convert from 'void' to 'LPWFSPINKEY *'

`malloc()` returns a `void*`, so a type-cast is needed here as well:

```
((WFSPINDATA*) (temp)) ->lpPinKeys = (LPWFSPINKEY*) malloc(sizeof(LPWFSPINKEY)*NumberOfKeys);
```

Or, using C++-style casts:

```
static_cast<WFSPINDATA*>(temp)->lpPinKeys = static_cast<LPWFSPINKEY*>(malloc(sizeof(LPWFSPINKEY)*NumberOfKeys));
```

Or, using C++-style allocation instead of C-style allocation:

```
static_cast<WFSPINDATA*>(temp)->lpPinKeys = new LPWFSPINKEY[NumberOfKeys];
// must use 'delete[] lpPinKeys' instead of 'free(lpPinKeys)' to deallocate the memory
```